# Phamlp in symfony project

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, haml, sass

Two days ago my manager say to me to start learn Phamlp.

I develop my projects whit symfony 1.4 and zurb foundations css framework. I'm wondering how to implement this technology in my project.

I search in Google for tutorials and posts for this, but can't find materials about this.

Is it posible to implement this technology in symfony framework 1.4 and how ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could write a plugin similar to this one http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfHamlViewPlugin